# How to get marker options in Google Maps API

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I have a `google.maps.Marker` object.

In the maps API v3 documentation there is a method named `setOptions({})` but no method called `getOptions()`.

I tried to call a method `getOptions()` expecting to get an object with the options data but no luck.

So for example how could I get the options of a `google.maps.Marker` or `google.maps.Circle` or `google.maps.Rectangle` overlay?

The reason I want this is because I need its current colors and opacity level in order to adjust a form elements so they are synchronized with the marker (rectangle, circle) state.

Comment: you can of course use `getMap`, `getPosition`, `getOpacity` etc to get individual properties, or just `get('foo')` to get any other properties that don't have an individual getter function.  I don't know of a single function to get them all

Comment: The new api doesn't support the `get('foo')` approach anymore.

Comment: Hey, did you ever solved it?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe my answer is late but it is good for new visitors.
You can check [Marker API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/marker) which contains many methods like `getOpacity()` and `setOpacity()`.
If you want to access the icon color then you can use `getIcon()` then check if it has the required property

```
var icon = marker.getIcon();
if(icon.hasOwnProperty("fillColor")){ // do something }
if(icon.hasOwnProperty("fillOpacity")){ // do something }
```

Also you can do the same thing with `getLabel()`

I hope I answered your question.